# Should the S be a capital letter in the iPhone S series?

Tags: iphone, spelling

For the iPhone S series, should the S next to the number be a capital letter or not? (iPhone 6s or iPhone 6S.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the official [Apple site](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/) it's always written with small "**s**".

You can also use iPhone 6 ;)

Comment: iPhone 6s is a mouthful.

Answer (score 0):

Going to http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/ and scrolling until you can find a reference in the regular text on the page finds the s is not capitalized.